# Notepad++ spellcheck not work with "comment tag"

Tags: notepad++, spell-check, hunspell

I am using plugin [DSpellCheck](https://github.com/Predelnik/DSpellCheck) in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

When editing an XML file I noticed that the spell checker does not check inside the "CDATA", like this:

`<![CDATA[My testt]]>`

What causes this is the exclamation mark (`!`)

Other example not work:

```
<!

testt

>
testt
```

The spell checker does not work inside "comment tag", but this work fine:

```
<!--

testt

>
testt
```

These are the delimiters in configs:

```
,.!?":;{}()[]\/=+-^$*<>|#$@%&~…№—«»–•©›“”· `→×
```

How to configure DSpellCheck/Hunspell to work?

Comment: It's possible this is intentional. CDATA is meant to be "This is seriously explicitly what I want to send, no matter what single quotes, double quotes, null characters or other chaff are present in here it REALLY SERIOUSLY is what I want to send". Otherwise it's an issue with the RegEx used to locate things to spellcheck.

Comment: @MrDoom No matter what it is. It is a text and a text should be spellchecked specially Comments, when others wanna read it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: You forget to add -- at the end of > . LIKE THIS <!-- dfsdf -->.
Also it works on my computer with no problem. What Ive found is that:

- You maybe have some problem in "Filetypes" of DSpellCheck settings, check it. It should be *.*
- Also when I unchecked the `Check only Comments and Strings If Possible` text inside CDATA went into what you want.

I post some pics:

#### When it was checked:

[image: Checkhed]

#### When I unckecked it:

[image: UnCkecked]

Comment: Disable `Check only Comments and Strings` work fine!

Comment: Im Glad ! ;) :D